# Naming ambiguity in constructive pointwise natural transformations and whiskering

Tags: ct.category-theory, terminology, convention

In the HoTT Book, the choice is made to talk about whiskering, rather than horizontal composition, because horizontal composition is ambiguous and only defined up to paths.  Naturally, there is left whiskering and right whiskering, and I think these are well-known to the category theory community.

When working on defining natural transformations pointwise, there is a similar problem, and I would like to know if there are good names for the two variants.
More precisely, given precategories $\mathcal C$, $\mathcal C'$, $\mathcal D$, $\mathcal C'$, functors $F, G : \mathcal C \to D$, functors $F', G' : \mathcal C' \to D'$, and natural transformations $T : F \to G$ and $T' : F' \to G'$, and letting $\mathcal B^{\mathcal A}$ denote the precategory of functors from $\mathcal A$ to $\mathcal B$ if $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ are precategories, and letting $G^F$ denote the functor $\mathcal D^{\mathcal C} \to \mathcal D'^{\mathcal C'}$ if $F$ is a functor $\mathcal C \to D$ and $G$ is a functor $\mathcal C' \to \mathcal D'$, we can form the pointwise natural transformations $F'^F \to F'^G$ and $F'^F \to G'^F$.  Is there a good and/or standard name for these natural transformations?  (Is one of them obviously "left" and the other "right"?) I'll probably end up notating the first as $F'^T$ and the second as $T'^F$ (or similarly if I choose a different notation for functor precategory), but I'd still like good names for them.

(Note: The reason I called them "pointwise", I think, was because I used them to construct the fact that if $F ⊣ G$, then $F^{\text{id}} ⊣ G^{\text{id}}$, which I called pointwise adjunctions, perhaps due to some connection I thought they had with pointwise Kan extensions (but which I can no longer recall).